# Stack Exchange Podcast RSS feed doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-norepro, feed, podcast

There's a "Podcast only" RSS feed: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/index.php/feed/, but when I  point my podcatcher to that URL I get nothing. I entered it in my browser and got an error page:

> ERROR: podcast is not a valid feed template.

Is this the place to bring this up? If so, what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying the W3C validator to

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/

I get:

http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.stackoverflow.com%2Ffeed%2F

> #### Congratulations!
>
> This is a valid RSS feed.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that. It's strange though, I used to get blog.stackoverflow.com/index.php?feed=podcast, which gives the error. And I still get that as the first hit when googling "stack exchange podcast rss". I hadn't noticed the URL changed a bit. But that must have happened in the last few minutes. Or am I going crazy. Anyway, works now, thanks.

Comment: I still get an error when I try to add all these urls with podkicker. It's an android app. This is the only podcast feed I've ever got an error adding.

Comment: The Stack Exchange Podcast RSS feed doesn't work in MyPOD either (also an Android app): http://www.my-pod.org . I've never had trouble with it in iTunes.